# How to build a dockerfile in centos without returned a non-zero code: 1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, devops

I'm tyring to do the create a container for tomcat by writing the dockerfile. After the build the dockerfile the error has been showed as below.

```
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install java -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What is it and how to build the docker file without this error?

Comment: Is there more to the error message than this?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], especially including the Dockerfile that produces this error?

Comment: Correct that the Dockerfile would semply the effort to find the answer and make also the question much clearer but the error in this case is quite self-explanatory

Comment: @Abd-98 did my solution wirk for you?

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, replace the line:

```
RUN yum install java -y
```

with:

```
RUN yum -y install java
```